# How to write an unit test for method which doesn't return anything

Tags: c#, nunit

I have a method which is fetching the values from appsetting.json file and assigning to a variables.
Here it is not returing anything.
So how to write a unit test for such a class and what to assert?
Any mocking is required?

```
public void GetConfig()
{
 var Request = new ConfigurationBuilder()            
    .AddJsonFile("usersettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            
 UserInputRequest = Request.GetSection("AppIdentitySettings").Get<List<UserRequest>>().First(); 
            
 var settings = new ConfigurationBuilder()            
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

 appSettings= settings.GetSection("somesettingssection").GetChildren().ToDictionary(x=>x.key,x=>x.value);
}
```

I tried to mock the configuration builder. But is it necessary to mock here?

Comment: you can mock the `ConfigurationBuilder` class and set up the `GetSection()`

Comment: 1. Step: _what_ do you want to test? Answer these: What needs to be true, so you consider this method "has run successfully"? What _may_ go wrong and how _should_ this method handle these errors?

Answer (score 0):

You test the the calls to `ConfigurationBuilder` if you injected that to the constructor of the test

```cs
public class MyConfigurationClass
{
    private readonly IConfigurationBuilder _builder;

    public MyConfigurationClass(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        _builder = builder;
    }
    public void GetConfig()
    {
         var Request = _builder.AddJsonFile("usersettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            
         UserInputRequest = Request.GetSection("AppIdentitySettings").Get<List<UserRequest>>().First(); 
            
         var settings = _builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

         appSettings = settings.GetSection("somesettingssection").GetChildren().ToDictionary(x=>x.key,x=>x.value);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class MyConfigurationClassTest
{
    public void MyTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var builder = // Create mock using a framework of your choice
        var sut = new MyConfigurationClass(builder);

        // Act
        sut.GetConfig();

        // Assert

        // Check calls to builder, using framework of your choice
    }
}
```

In your current setup, the only thing you can really test is the value of `appSettings`, but the code will make a call to an actual file, which can start to get complicated

Comment: Ok, this means I need to mock configuration builder and check the values of appsettings